# How to plot each list element with same x axis?

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, plot

Reproducible example:

```
a <- 2
b <- 1
tau <- 2

t <- seq(1,3,1)
y <- seq(0,10,1)

G.fun <- function(x,shape,scale){pgamma(x,shape,scale)}

G <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(t))
for (t in 1:length(t)){
  G[[t]] <- G.fun(y,shape = a*t, scale = b)
}
```

How can I plot each element of G on a same plot given the x axis is same for all which is y <- seq(0,10,1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### base R

```r
plot(y, G[[1]], pch = 16, type = "b")
for (i in seq_along(G)[-1]) points(y, G[[i]], type = "b", pch = 16, col = i)
```

[image: sample base-R plot]

### ggplot

(I'll use `tidyr` to reshape it.)

```r
dat <- cbind(y=y, setNames(as.data.frame(G), c("A","B","C")))
dat2 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, -y)
head(dat2)
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#       y name     value
#   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
# 1     0 A     0       
# 2     0 B     0       
# 3     0 C     0       
# 4     1 A     0.264   
# 5     1 B     0.0190  
# 6     1 C     0.000594
ggplot(dat2, aes(y, value, color = name)) + geom_path()
```

[image: ggplot2 sample plot]

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you could also use the `matplot` function. First you have to ensure you have a matrix from your list:

```
mat <- do.call(cbind, G) #or even unname(as.matrix(data.frame(G)))
matplot(y, mat, type = "b")
```

[image]

This can be written as `matplot(y, do.call(cbind, G), type = "b")`